# How to change Outlook back to Hotmail 2018

Tags: outlook.com

I was suddenly changed from my regular Hotmail setting to Outlook without my permission.

Suddenly everything were changed, the "sorting" only has `date`, `from` and `size`; missing all other sort options as in the past. I want my emails sort by `subject`.

So, please give me back my Hotmail. I don't like the Outlook.

The new Outlook doesn't have the option to switch back.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.
All hotmail.com users have been migrated/upgraded to outlook.com